# Difference between List And ListQueue

Tags: dart

What's the difference between [List](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-core/List-class.html) And [ListQueue](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.2/dart-collection/ListQueue-class.html) in Dart programming language? If one can perform the same operations on List, what's the use of ListQueue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `ListQueue` is not a `List`. It implements the `Queue` interface and offers (amortized) constant time `addFirst`/`removeFirst`/`addLast`/`removeLast` operations. A `List` can only do that for `addLast`/`removeLast`. It costs a little extra overhead for each element access, so you shouldn't use a `Queue` where a `List` would suffice.

The `ListQueue` is an implementation class for the abstract `Queue` interface. It's based on an underlying list, which is why it's named the way it is (like a `HashSet` is named after the way it implements the `Set` interface).

Comment: That's the answer for the first part of the question, thank you. And what are advantages of using ListQueue if one can do same things using List? Are there significant differences in terms of speed?

Comment: As lrn explained, a `ListQueue` offers (amortized) constant-time insertion or removal from the beginning of the queue.  That is not true for a `List`; inserting or removing from the beginning of a `List` would require moving all existing elements, making that an O(n) operation.

Comment: Added a little extra on that.